# why ios scrollViewDidScroll not slide but scrollviewdidscroll was called

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview

I want to slide to the bottom of the page when the judge to load more data, but this function（scrollviewdidscroll） at the beginning of the call, I would like to know why.

thankyou

Comment: Implement appropriate delegate for event action in scrollview from this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate

Comment: That will call due to content being changed and content size set to scrollview, when you are setting contentSize to your scrollview, that will respond to their delegate at first time itself.